# Enum with associated value conforming to CaseIterable, RawRepresentable

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to make enum with associated value conform to CaseIterable, RawRepresentable. I'm fine with some default values for associated values when initializing by rawValue.

```
enum GenresAssociated: CaseIterable, RawRepresentable, Equatable {
    case unknown(String)
    case blues(String)
    case classical(String)
    // Implementing CaseIterable
    typealias AllCases = [GenresAssociated]
    // Enums can have no storage, but the class they are in CAN. Note 'static' in declaration
    static var allCases: [GenresAssociated] = [.unknown(""), .blues(""), .classical("")]


    typealias RawValue = Int
    var rawValue: Int {

        // MARK: This causes a crash for unknown reason
        return GenresAssociated.allCases.firstIndex(where: {  if case self = $0 { return true } else { return false } } ) ?? 0
    }
    init?(rawValue: Int) {
        guard GenresAssociated.allCases.indices.contains(rawValue) else { return nil }
        self = GenresAssociated.allCases[rawValue]
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it without switching manually by all the cases, i.e. without such code:

```
    typealias RawValue = Int
    var rawValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case .unknown:
            return 0
        case .blues:
            return 1
        case .classical:
            return 2
        }
    }
```

What's notable is that very similar code works just fine, for example

```
enum EnumWithValue {
    case one(NSString!), two(NSString!), three(NSString!)
}

let arrayOfEnumsWithValues: [EnumWithValue] = [.one(nil), .two(nil), .three("Hey")]

if let index = arrayOfEnumsWithValues.firstIndex(where: { if case .two = $0 { return true }; return false }) {
    print(".two found at index \(index)") //prints ".two found at index 1"
}
```

Comment: I would not use `RawRepresentable` on an enumeration with associated values, as the `RawRepresentable` protocol indicates, that you can "switch back and forth between a custom type and an associated RawValue type without losing the value of the original RawRepresentable type" (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable). That would mean that your associated values are somehow contained in the `rawValue` as well.

Comment: Totally agree, @Palle. The data structure is a kind of kext (and also a stress-test for Enum). Yes, I'm playing with Enums here, trying to master them.

Answer (score 6):

I got it finally to work with `Mirror`!

```
var rawValue: Int {
    let selfCaseName = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first!.label!

    return GenresAssociated.allCases.firstIndex(where: { (genre) in
        let switchingCaseName = Mirror(reflecting: genre).children.first!.label!

        return switchingCaseName == selfCaseName
    })!
}
```

Don't mind the force unwrapping, it is safe here.

Comment: Definitely a working solution, @J. Doe. I also sometimes use Mirror as the last resort. But I'm also trying to find out what is wrong with my syntax, i.e
am I creating memory cycle or running into issue with laziness or faulting, or something like that.

Comment: Would you please add some more details about how / why this works. This has the potential to be a very popular (highly upvoted) and useful answer. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

This parameter will work with enums containing both rawValue cases and cases with associatedValues:

```
var caseName: String { 
   let result = String(describing: self)
   let assocValName = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first?.label ?? "failed"

   return !result.contains("(") ? result : assocValName
}
```