# Unwrapping associated value for all cases in switch

Tags: swift, xcode, switch-statement, associated-value

I have an enum similar to this, where all cases contain the same associated value `content`:

```swift
enum RowType {
    case single(_ content: [Any])
    case double(_ content: [Any])
    case triple(_ content: [Any])
    ...
}
```

I know I could just use a `struct` with a `rowType` and a `content` attribute, but let's please not discuss this, but rather have a look at the following:
When I want to switch all the cases, I could of course do this:

```swift
switch row {
case .single(let content):
    // do anything
    break
case .double(let content):
    // ...
...
}
```

or even:

```swift
switch row {
case .single(let content), .double(let content), ...:
    // do the same thing for all cases
    break
}
```

Now my enum contains a few more cases and is likely to grow further while under development, so it's inconvenient for me to list all cases in the same `case` statement just to unwrap the `content` argument.

So I got curious and wondered: **Can I somehow "wildcard" the enum case itself and still unwrap the `content` field?** Like a `default` case with associated value...

I was hoping to be able to do **something like** ...

```swift
switch row {
case _(let content):
    // do something
    break
}
```

... or maybe accessing the associated value in the default case.

I did a bit of research but couldn't find an answer, so I'm excited for your thoughts.

Comment: Such a feature does not exist. Using  a struct with a rowType and a content attribute instead would be the correct approach.

Comment: A possible solution is to add a computed property to your enum that contains a switch that then returns your. content. You still need to include all possibilities but only once.

Comment: It's not possible right now, even because every case could contain different kind of associated values (or not having at all) and the compiler wouldn't be able to handle all of them with a single wildcard

Comment: @MichaelSalmon ah well that's actually a great idea! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio yes it _could_, but can't I tell him to rely on that, something like force unwrapping the enum value? Something like a case for "Whenever I can unwrap an associated value with type `[Any]` ". I mean, it's still a switch which provides a default clause as a fallback... Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Playground.

```
enum RowType {
case single(_ content: [Any])
case double(_ content: [Any])
case triple(_ content: [Any])
case noVal

var associatedValue: Any? {
    get {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        if let associated = mirror.children.first {
            return  associated.value
        }
        print("WARNING: Enum option of \(self) does not have an associated value")
        return  nil
    }
  }
}

let row : RowType = .double([1,2,3])
let rowNoVal : RowType = .noVal
row.associatedValue
rowNoVal.associatedValue
```

Comment: Works pretty fine actually, thanks for sharing! Can you think of a "safer" variant, for example without Mirror?

Comment: I was searching for the safer variant without Mirror, @Muli. (You can see that by my Q&A here.) Here is one of attempts to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55212028/enum-with-associated-value-conforming-to-caseiterable-rawrepresentable
Note that in static cases rawValues can do the job instead.

Comment: Otherwise I can only think of such a straightforward solution, @Muli:
`var associatedValue: Any? {
    get {
        switch self {
        case .single(let content), .double(let content), .triple(let content):
            return content
        default:
            return nil
        }

    }
  }
}`

Comment: Yup, looks nice! Also your straightforward solution seems like a nice workaround. Thank you